# hibernate multi source data

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate, сессия

Не могу найти информацию как можно в hibernate работать с двумя источниками данных. С двумя разными базами данных.

Можно создать две разные фабрики для двух источников, но тогда джойнить одну сущность к другой не получается.

Возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 0):

Если кратко, то:

> Можно создать две разные фабрики для двух источников, но тогда джойнить одну сущность к другой не получается.

**да** - работать с 2 источниками данных (datasource) вы можете, но использовать join между таблицами разных БД (и соответственно datasource) - **нет**.

Как вариант решения проблемы - если ваши БД поддерживают создание dblink-ов (например Oracle DB), то можно их связать и обращаться из одной БД к таблицам другой (возможно, для этого также придется создать view).
Аналогичный вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552330/doing-a-join-over-2-tables-in-different-databases-using-hibernate%20enSO)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас дблинками и пользуемся. Однако это не удобно. Приходится тратить время на создание и сопровождение внешних таблиц.